# file not being written after I hit submit button

Tags: php, forms, submit, isset

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']))
 /////code here//////
 /////the program actually gets inside this if statement after the user submits login info

 if(strpos(file_get_contents("accounts.txt"),$text) !== false) : ?>

 /////html form displays here...and the submit button name of the form is submitbtn//////
<input type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="Submit" onclick="giveaway()">

 <?php endif; ?>    

 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submitbtn']))
 //////the content here never runs, regardless if I click submit or not/////
```

does anyone know why when I click on the submit button of the form, the php code after it doesn't run? It never gets inside the if statement

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo: `submit_btn` versus `submitbtn`

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submitbtn']))
 /////code here//////
 /////the program actually gets inside this if statement after the user submits login info

 if(strpos(file_get_contents("accounts.txt"),$text) !== false) : ?>

 /////html form displays here...and the submit button name of the form is submitbtn//////
<input type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="Submit" onclick="giveaway()">

 <?php endif; ?>    

 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submitbtn']))
 //////the content here never runs, regardless if I click submit or not/////
```

Comment: submit_btn is the submit name for the LOGIN form... submitbtn is the name of the second form... the page has 2 forms

Comment: But the first button is not pressed, if you press the next one in the next form / website call. You have to store somehow, that a user is logged in. SESSIONS

Comment: the first button is pressed first ...then the form appears...and when he presses the submit of the form, nothing happens

Comment: As said, you canNOT press two buttons at the same time.

Comment: so how would I fix that?

Comment: Do you have a `method="post"` on your form? Are you posting it to the same PHP page?